# How use connect in react redux

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-2016

What is preset for webpack to handel connect decorate 
I tried to run webpack but nothing happened

```
/*

connect(store)

class App extends React.Component{

}
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `connect()` you need to define a special function called `mapStateToProps` which tells us how to transform the Redux store state into the props. For example, VisibleTodoList needs to calculate todos to pass to the TodoList, so we define a function that filters the state.todos according to the state.visibilityFilter, and use it in its mapStateToProps:

```
const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch (filter) {
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed)
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
    default:
      return todos
  }
}
 
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    todos: getVisibleTodos(state.todos, state.visibilityFilter)
  }
}
```

Now o have to dispatch action to read the state. To do that you can use `mapDispatchToProps()` function that receives the `dispatch()` method and returns callback props that you want to inject into the component.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onTodoClick: id => {
      dispatch(toggleTodo(id))
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, using VisibleTodoList by calling connect() and passing these two functions:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
 
const VisibleTodoList = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TodoList)
 
export default VisibleTodoList
```